# como conectar a un webservice y mandar xml en php

Tags: php, xml, codeigniter, curl

Tengo un proyecto en codeigneiter , estoy tratando de hacer una conexion por curl con un web service de timbrado , estoy usando el codigo que ellos me proporcionaron en php , el cual esta bien , solo que al agregar la variable $ch = curl_init() deja de funcionar mi vista o me marca un error , no se si esa libreria debe importarse segun yo ya viene incluida en php , de lo contrario , ayuda plis soy nuevo trabajando en esto

```
function GenerarXml(){


<?php
$xml="";
   //Armando el Request para la peticiòn SOAP
   $xml  = "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\n";
   $xml .= "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:tem=\"http://tempuri.org/\" xmlns:tes=\"http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/TES.V33.CFDI.Negocios\">\n";  
  $xml .= "<soapenv:Header/>\n";
  $xml .= "<soapenv:Body>\n";
  $xml .= "    <tem:GenerarCFDI>\n";
  $xml .= "    <tem:credenciales>\n";
  $xml .= "    <tes:Cuenta>TES030201001</tes:Cuenta>\n";
  $xml .= "    <tes:Password>Pruebas2017$</tes:Password>\n";
  $xml .= "    <tes:Usuario>TES030201001</tes:Usuario>\n";
  $xml .= "    </tem:credenciales>\n";
  $xml .= "    <tem:cfdi>\n";
  $xml .= "    <tes:ClaveCFDI>FAC</tes:ClaveCFDI>\n";
  $xml .= "    <tes:Conceptos>\n";
  $xml .= "    <tes:ConceptoR>\n";
  $xml .= "    <tes:Cantidad>1.7</tes:Cantidad>\n";
  $xml .= "    <tes:ClaveProdServ>01010101</tes:ClaveProdServ>\n";
  $xml .= "    <tes:ClaveUnidad>F52</tes:ClaveUnidad>\n";
  $xml .= "    <tes:Descripcion>ZAMAC</tes:Descripcion>\n";
  $xml .= "    <tes:Importe>17000.00</tes:Importe>\n";
  $xml .= "    <tes:Impuestos>\n";
  $xml .= "    <tes:Traslados>\n";
  $xml .= "    <tes:TrasladoConceptoR>\n";
  $xml .= "    <tes:Base>17000</tes:Base>\n";
  $xml .= "    <tes:Importe>2720.00</tes:Importe>\n";
  $xml .= "    <tes:Impuesto>002</tes:Impuesto>\n";
  $xml .= "    <tes:TasaOCuota>0.160000</tes:TasaOCuota>\n";
  $xml .= "    <tes:TipoFactor>Tasa</tes:TipoFactor>\n";
  $xml .= "    </tes:TrasladoConceptoR>\n";
  $xml .= "    </tes:Traslados>\n";
  $xml .= "    </tes:Impuestos>\n";
  $xml .= "    <tes:NoIdentificacion>00003</tes:NoIdentificacion>\n";
  $xml .= "    <tes:Unidad>TONELADA</tes:Unidad>\n";
  $xml .= "    <tes:ValorUnitario>10000.00</tes:ValorUnitario>\n";
  $xml .= "    </tes:ConceptoR>\n";
  $xml .= "    </tes:Conceptos>\n";
  $xml .= "    <tes:CondicionesDePago>CONDICIONES</tes:CondicionesDePago>\n";
  $xml .= "    <tes:Emisor>\n";
  $xml .= "    <tes:Nombre>HORACIO LLANOS</tes:Nombre>\n";
  $xml .= "    <tes:RegimenFiscal>601</tes:RegimenFiscal>\n";
  $xml .= "    </tes:Emisor>\n";
  $xml .= "    <tes:FormaPago>01</tes:FormaPago>\n";
  $xml .= "    <tes:LugarExpedicion>45079</tes:LugarExpedicion>\n";
  $xml .= "    <tes:MetodoPago>PUE</tes:MetodoPago>\n";
  $xml .= "    <tes:Moneda>MXN</tes:Moneda>\n";  
  $xml .= "    <tes:Receptor>\n";   
  $xml .= "    <tes:Nombre>RAFAEL ALEJANDRO HERNÁNDEZ PALACIOS</tes:Nombre>\n";
  $xml .= "    <tes:Rfc>TEST010203001</tes:Rfc>\n";
  $xml .= "    <tes:UsoCFDI>G01</tes:UsoCFDI>\n";
  $xml .= "    </tes:Receptor>\n";
  $xml .= "    <tes:Referencia>0001</tes:Referencia>\n";
  $xml .= "    <tes:SubTotal>17000.00</tes:SubTotal>\n";
  $xml .= "    <tes:Total>19720.00</tes:Total>\n";
  $xml .= "    </tem:cfdi>\n";
  $xml .= "    </tem:GenerarCFDI>\n";
  $xml .= "    </soapenv:Body>\n";
  $xml .= "    </soapenv:Envelope>\n";

  //creo un archivo soap_reequest.xml e introduzco la cadena_xml
    $new_xml = fopen ("./soap-request.xml", "w");
    fwrite($new_xml,$xml);
    fclose($new_xml);
    //Esta parde es el Header de la peticion SOAP y en ella se incluye el contenido de la pagina del servicio
  $header = array(
    "POST /CR33Test/ConexionRemota.svc HTTP/1.1",
    "Host: www.fel.mx",
    "Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8",
    "Content-Length: ".strlen($xml),
    "SOAPAction: \"http://tempuri.org/IConexionRemota/GenerarCFDI\""
  );

  $ch=curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.fel.mx/CR33Test/ConexionRemota.svc?WSDL");
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,        30);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,           true );
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,     $xml);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,     $header);

// Respuesta del webservice
            $response = curl_exec($ch; 
            curl_close($ch;
            print $response;
//se guarda del web service (Tipo de Respuesta, XML Timbrado y CBB)         
    $new_xml = fopen ("./soap-response.xml", "w");
    fwrite($new_xml, $response);
    fclose($new_xml);

?>
var xml =  <?= json_encode($xml); ?>

var respuesta =  <?= json_encode($response); ?>

var newxml =  <?= json_encode($new_xml); ?>

console.log(xml);
console.log(respuesta);
console.log(newxml);

}
```

---

asi me aparece el error y la linea del

```
function GenerarXml(){


<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><s:Body><GenerarCFDIResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"><GenerarCFDIResult xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/TES.V33.CFDI.Negocios" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><a:CBB i:nil="true"/><a:CodigoConfirmacion i:nil="true"/><a:ErrorDetallado>Código de error: </a:ErrorDetallado><a:ErrorGeneral>Error de autenticación de usuario, 1 intentos realizados.</a:ErrorGeneral><a:FechaGenerada i:nil="true"/><a:FolioGenerado i:nil="true"/><a:OperacionExitosa>false</a:OperacionExitosa><a:PDF i:nil="true"/><a:XML i:nil="true"/></GenerarCFDIResult></GenerarCFDIResponse></s:Body></s:Envelope>var xml =  "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\n<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=\"http:\/\/schemas.xmlsoap.org\/soap\/envelope\/\" xmlns:tem=\"http:\/\/tempuri.org\/\" xmlns:tes=\"http:\/\/schemas.datacontract.org\/2004\/07\/TES.V33.CFDI.Negocios\">\n<soapenv:Header\/>\n<soapenv:Body>\n\t   <tem:GenerarCFDI>\n    <tem:credenciales>\n    <tes:Cuenta>TES030201001<\/tes:Cuenta>\n    <tes:Password>Pruebas2017$<\/tes:Password>\n    <tes:Usuario>TES030201001<\/tes:Usuario>\n    <\/tem:credenciales>\n    <tem:cfdi>\n    <tes:ClaveCFDI>FAC<\/tes:ClaveCFDI>\n    <tes:Conceptos>\n\t   <tes:ConceptoR>\n    <tes:Cantidad>1.7<\/tes:Cantidad>\n    <tes:ClaveProdServ>01010101<\/tes:ClaveProdServ>\n    <tes:ClaveUnidad>F52<\/tes:ClaveUnidad>\n    <tes:Descripcion>ZAMAC<\/tes:Descripcion>\n    <tes:Importe>17000.00<\/tes:Importe>\n    <tes:Impuestos>\n    <tes:Traslados>\n    <tes:TrasladoConceptoR>\n    <tes:Base>17000<\/tes:Base>\n    <tes:Importe>2720.00<\/tes:Importe>\n    <tes:Impuesto>002<\/tes:Impuesto>\n    <tes:TasaOCuota>0.160000<\/tes:TasaOCuota>\n    <tes:TipoFactor>Tasa<\/tes:TipoFactor>\n    <\/tes:TrasladoConceptoR>\n    <\/tes:Traslados>\n    <\/tes:Impuestos>\n    <tes:NoIdentificacion>00003<\/tes:NoIdentificacion>\n    <tes:Unidad>TONELADA<\/tes:Unidad>\n    <tes:ValorUnitario>10000.00<\/tes:ValorUnitario>\n    <\/tes:ConceptoR>\n    <\/tes:Conceptos>\n    <tes:CondicionesDePago>CONDICIONES<\/tes:CondicionesDePago>\n\t   <tes:Emisor>\n    <tes:Nombre>HORACIO LLANOS<\/tes:Nombre>\n    <tes:RegimenFiscal>601<\/tes:RegimenFiscal>\n    <\/tes:Emisor>\n    <tes:FormaPago>01<\/tes:FormaPago>\n    <tes:LugarExpedicion>45079<\/tes:LugarExpedicion>\n    <tes:MetodoPago>PUE<\/tes:MetodoPago>\n    <tes:Moneda>MXN<\/tes:Moneda>\n    <tes:Receptor>\n    <tes:Nombre>RAFAEL ALEJANDRO HERN\u00c1NDEZ PALACIOS<\/tes:Nombre>\n    <tes:Rfc>TEST010203001<\/tes:Rfc>\n    <tes:UsoCFDI>G01<\/tes:UsoCFDI>\n    <\/tes:Receptor>\n    <tes:Referencia>0001<\/tes:Referencia>\n    <tes:SubTotal>17000.00<\/tes:SubTotal>\n    <tes:Total>19720.00<\/tes:Total>\n    <\/tem:cfdi>\n    <\/tem:GenerarCFDI>\n    <\/soapenv:Body>\n    <\/soapenv:Envelope>\n"
var respuesta =  "<s:Envelope xmlns:s=\"http:\/\/schemas.xmlsoap.org\/soap\/envelope\/\"><s:Body><GenerarCFDIResponse xmlns=\"http:\/\/tempuri.org\/\"><GenerarCFDIResult xmlns:a=\"http:\/\/schemas.datacontract.org\/2004\/07\/TES.V33.CFDI.Negocios\" xmlns:i=\"http:\/\/www.w3.org\/2001\/XMLSchema-instance\"><a:CBB i:nil=\"true\"\/><a:CodigoConfirmacion i:nil=\"true\"\/><a:ErrorDetallado>C\u00f3digo de error: <\/a:ErrorDetallado><a:ErrorGeneral>Error de autenticaci\u00f3n de usuario, 1 intentos realizados.<\/a:ErrorGeneral><a:FechaGenerada i:nil=\"true\"\/><a:FolioGenerado i:nil=\"true\"\/><a:OperacionExitosa>false<\/a:OperacionExitosa><a:PDF i:nil=\"true\"\/><a:XML i:nil=\"true\"\/><\/GenerarCFDIResult><\/GenerarCFDIResponse><\/s:Body><\/s:Envelope>"
var newxml =  
console.log(xml);
console.log(respuesta);
console.log(newxml);

}
```

---

asi quedo con el try catch , pero me sigue marcando ese error que te menciono , anexare imagen del error :
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
function GenerarXml(){


<?php
$xml="";
   //Armando el Request para la peticiòn SOAP
   $xml  = "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\n";
   $xml .= "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:tem=\"http://tempuri.org/\" xmlns:tes=\"http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/TES.V33.CFDI.Negocios\">\n";  
  $xml .= "<soapenv:Header/>\n";
  $xml .= "<soapenv:Body>\n";
  $xml .= "    <tem:GenerarCFDI>\n";
  $xml .= "    <tem:credenciales>\n";
  $xml .= "    <tes:Cuenta>TES030201001</tes:Cuenta>\n";
  $xml .= "    <tes:Password>Pruebas2017$</tes:Password>\n";
  $xml .= "    <tes:Usuario>TES030201001</tes:Usuario>\n";
  $xml .= "    </tem:credenciales>\n";
  $xml .= "    <tem:cfdi>\n";
  $xml .= "    <tes:ClaveCFDI>FAC</tes:ClaveCFDI>\n";
  $xml .= "    <tes:Conceptos>\n";
  $xml .= "    <tes:ConceptoR>\n";
  $xml .= "    <tes:Cantidad>1.7</tes:Cantidad>\n";
  $xml .= "    <tes:ClaveProdServ>01010101</tes:ClaveProdServ>\n";
  $xml .= "    <tes:ClaveUnidad>F52</tes:ClaveUnidad>\n";
  $xml .= "    <tes:Descripcion>ZAMAC</tes:Descripcion>\n";
  $xml .= "    <tes:Importe>17000.00</tes:Importe>\n";
  $xml .= "    <tes:Impuestos>\n";
  $xml .= "    <tes:Traslados>\n";
  $xml .= "    <tes:TrasladoConceptoR>\n";
  $xml .= "    <tes:Base>17000</tes:Base>\n";
  $xml .= "    <tes:Importe>2720.00</tes:Importe>\n";
  $xml .= "    <tes:Impuesto>002</tes:Impuesto>\n";
  $xml .= "    <tes:TasaOCuota>0.160000</tes:TasaOCuota>\n";
  $xml .= "    <tes:TipoFactor>Tasa</tes:TipoFactor>\n";
  $xml .= "    </tes:TrasladoConceptoR>\n";
  $xml .= "    </tes:Traslados>\n";
  $xml .= "    </tes:Impuestos>\n";
  $xml .= "    <tes:NoIdentificacion>00003</tes:NoIdentificacion>\n";
  $xml .= "    <tes:Unidad>TONELADA</tes:Unidad>\n";
  $xml .= "    <tes:ValorUnitario>10000.00</tes:ValorUnitario>\n";
  $xml .= "    </tes:ConceptoR>\n";
  $xml .= "    </tes:Conceptos>\n";
  $xml .= "    <tes:CondicionesDePago>CONDICIONES</tes:CondicionesDePago>\n";
  $xml .= "    <tes:Emisor>\n";
  $xml .= "    <tes:Nombre>HORACIO LLANOS</tes:Nombre>\n";
  $xml .= "    <tes:RegimenFiscal>601</tes:RegimenFiscal>\n";
  $xml .= "    </tes:Emisor>\n";
  $xml .= "    <tes:FormaPago>01</tes:FormaPago>\n";
  $xml .= "    <tes:LugarExpedicion>45079</tes:LugarExpedicion>\n";
  $xml .= "    <tes:MetodoPago>PUE</tes:MetodoPago>\n";
  $xml .= "    <tes:Moneda>MXN</tes:Moneda>\n";  
  $xml .= "    <tes:Receptor>\n";   
  $xml .= "    <tes:Nombre>RAFAEL ALEJANDRO HERNÁNDEZ PALACIOS</tes:Nombre>\n";
  $xml .= "    <tes:Rfc>TEST010203001</tes:Rfc>\n";
  $xml .= "    <tes:UsoCFDI>G01</tes:UsoCFDI>\n";
  $xml .= "    </tes:Receptor>\n";
  $xml .= "    <tes:Referencia>0001</tes:Referencia>\n";
  $xml .= "    <tes:SubTotal>17000.00</tes:SubTotal>\n";
  $xml .= "    <tes:Total>19720.00</tes:Total>\n";
  $xml .= "    </tem:cfdi>\n";
  $xml .= "    </tem:GenerarCFDI>\n";
  $xml .= "    </soapenv:Body>\n";
  $xml .= "    </soapenv:Envelope>\n";

  //creo un archivo soap_reequest.xml e introduzco la cadena_xml
    $first_xml = fopen ("./soap-request.xml", "w");
    fwrite($first_xml,$xml);
    fclose($first_xml);
    //Esta parde es el Header de la peticion SOAP y en ella se incluye el contenido de la pagina del servicio
  $header = array(
    "POST /CR33Test/ConexionRemota.svc HTTP/1.1",
    "Host: www.fel.mx",
    "Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8",
    "Content-Length: ".strlen($xml),
    "SOAPAction: \"http://tempuri.org/IConexionRemota/GenerarCFDI\""
  );

  try{
    $ch = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.fel.mx/CR33Test/ConexionRemota.svc?WSDL");
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,        30);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,           true );
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,     $xml);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,     $header);

}catch(Exception $e){
    print_r($e);
}



// Respuesta del webservice
            $response = curl_exec($ch); 
            curl_close($ch);
            print $response;
//se guarda del web service (Tipo de Respuesta, XML Timbrado y CBB)         
    $sec_xml = fopen ("./soap-response.xml", "w");
    fwrite($sec_xml, $response);
    fclose($sec_xml);

?>
var xml =  <?= json_encode($xml); ?>

var respuesta =  <?= json_encode($response); ?>

var newxml =  <?= json_encode($new_xml); ?>

console.log(xml);
console.log(respuesta);
console.log(newxml);

}
```

este es el error en sources:
y este me muestra en sources en la consola de desarrollador:

> function GenerarXml(){
>
> Código de error:
>   Error de autenticación de usuario,
>   1 intentos realizados.falsevar
>   xml =  "\n\n\n\n\t
>   \n    \n
>   TES030201001</tes:Cuenta>\n
>   Pruebas2017$</tes:Password>\n
>   TES030201001</tes:Usuario>\n    </tem:credenciales>\n
>   \n    FAC</tes:ClaveCFDI>\n
>   \n\t   \n
>   1.7</tes:Cantidad>\n
>   01010101</tes:ClaveProdServ>\n
>   F52</tes:ClaveUnidad>\n
>   ZAMAC</tes:Descripcion>\n
>   17000.00</tes:Importe>\n    \n
>   \n    \n
>   17000</tes:Base>\n    2720.00</tes:Importe>\n
>   002</tes:Impuesto>\n
>   0.160000</tes:TasaOCuota>\n
>   Tasa</tes:TipoFactor>\n
>   </tes:TrasladoConceptoR>\n    </tes:Traslados>\n
>   </tes:Impuestos>\n
>   00003</tes:NoIdentificacion>\n
>   TONELADA</tes:Unidad>\n
>   10000.00</tes:ValorUnitario>\n
>   </tes:ConceptoR>\n    </tes:Conceptos>\n
>   CONDICIONES</tes:CondicionesDePago>\n\t
>   \n    HORACIO LLANOS</tes:Nombre>\n
>   601</tes:RegimenFiscal>\n    </tes:Emisor>\n
>   01</tes:FormaPago>\n
>   45079</tes:LugarExpedicion>\n
>   PUE</tes:MetodoPago>\n
>   MXN</tes:Moneda>\n    \n
>   RAFAEL ALEJANDRO HERN\u00c1NDEZ PALACIOS</tes:Nombre>\n
>   TEST010203001</tes:Rfc>\n
>   G01</tes:UsoCFDI>\n    </tes:Receptor>\n
>   0001</tes:Referencia>\n
>   17000.00</tes:SubTotal>\n
>   19720.00</tes:Total>\n    </tem:cfdi>\n
>   </tem:GenerarCFDI>\n    </soapenv:Body>\n    </soapenv:Envelope>\n"
>       var respuesta =  "C\u00f3digo de error:
>   </a:ErrorDetallado>Error de autenticaci\u00f3n de
>   usuario, 1 intentos realizados.</a:ErrorGeneral>false</a:OperacionExitosa></GenerarCFDIResult></GenerarCFDIResponse></s:Body></s:Envelope>"
>       var newxml =
>       console.log(xml);
>       console.log(respuesta);
>       console.log(newxml);
>
> ```
> }
> ```

Comment: porque no lo haces con [soapClient](http://php.net/manual/es/class.soapclient.php) de PHP

Comment: Cuidado con los datos sensibles  (usuario, contraseña, cuenta y host) que estás mostrando. Alguien podría hacer un mal uso, te recomiendo que los ocultes de algún modo.

Comment: Veo que no has entendido como funciona [es.so]. La parte de "Tu respuesta" se utiliza para RESPONDER. Si lo que quieres es añadir información a tu pregunta, lo que debes hacer es pulsar en [edit] y añadirla dentro del cuerpo de tu pregunta.

Comment: Hola @debekmendoza , debes atender lo que comenta Pikoh, por favor no agregues actualizaciones como respuestas, tu preguna en realidad no es clara, es **muy importante leer [ask]** para plantear tu pregunta correctamente.

Comment: ok editare la pregunta y tratare de hacerla mas clara agregando toda la informacion necesaria , muchas gracias , es la primera vez que pregunto aqui

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Efectivamente puedes usar SoapClient, pero para el caso particular, esta complicado debido a como esta estructurado el wsdl, deberias de mandar todos los parametros en un arreglo. Coloca la llamada `curl_init` sobre un bloque de exepcion, y dinos cual es tu resultado, para hacer llamadas curl, también debes incluir la librería php-curl, te recomiendo usar el software Soap-UI, en el puedes ver cuales son los métodos que expone el servicio y los parametros que son requeridos.

```
try{
$ch = curl_init();
.......
}catch(Exception $e){
print_r($e);
}
```

Para habilitar la librería, en tu carpeta de instalación wamp por ejemplo, debes buscar el fichero bin/php/php56/php.ini, al igual que en el fichero bin/apache/apache2/php.ini y descomentas la linea

```
extension=php_curl.dll
```

una vez editados los ficheros, reinicias tu servicios de wamp

Ejemplo de llamado con SoapClient, debes incluir la libreria php-soap

```
$client = new SoapClient("https://www.fel.mx/CR33Test/ConexionRemota.svc?WSDL");
$params = array('codigo' => $parametro);
$result = $client->miMetodo($params);
```

Comment: acabo de hacer el try catch el problema es que no puedo ver el error por que cuando agrego el curl_init() mi vista deja de cargar y no puedo ver la consola ni nada solo se queda la pagina en blanco

Comment: verifica tus lineas `$response = curl_exec($ch;` y `close($ch;` les falta un parentesis a cada una

Comment: ok ya corrio , esa funcion la tengo en el onclick de un boton , el problema tambien es que cuando agrego ese bloque me marca un error :
Unexpected token < 
pero al ir al error no muestra absolutamente nada , eso me habia pasado con el xml pq no tenia inicializada la variable xml pero al declararla como xml=""; se soluciono , pero en este caso que hago pq no es un texto , otra , como incluyo la libreria php-curl?

Comment: si usas windows, probablemente debas agregar un dll a tu archivo config, si usas linux debes instalar la libreria php-curl. En vez de utilizar la concatenación con doble comilla, te recomiendo utilizar la forma heredoc, ahi y puedes evitar la confusión de escapar los caracteres. http://php.net/manual/es/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc, podrias colocar cual es el otro error que te marca, y quien te lo marca, php o javascript

Comment: ok deja voy checando eso , estoy en window entonces deja veo lo del dll , el otro error cuando agrego el $ch=curl_init() me sale esto en la consola Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < , y eso automaticamente cuando clickeo el boton me sale que la funcion generarxml() no esta definida , y el error me lleva al curl_init() , por cierto me sale una ruta de mi proyecto index.php?/pacientes/cuenta/27:685  pero en sources al querer ver el error aparece en blanco y en el archivo cuenta que es donde tengo mi funcion nisiquiera tengo 685 lineas

Comment: el error me lo marca javascript

Comment: es probable que el último valor `newxml` no este declarado adecuadamente. `fopen` te devuelve un recurso o puntero para poder escribir en el archivo, y `fclose` lo cierra, por lo que la variable que estas asignando a `newxml` sea un booleano.

Comment: antes del curl se crea un request.xml si lo crea , en el segundo se guarda la respuesta , por eso se abre nuevamente , igual podria cambiar la la variable , por cierto con de lo php-curl , el sistema esta hosteado en godaddy , eso del dll lo debo habilitar desde cpanel o algo asi desde el servidor?

Comment: es probable que ya este habilitado, coloca un fichero en tu carpeta publica que se llame `info.php` y le agregas la linea de código `phpinfo();`, te mostrara como está configurado tu servidor y ahi buscas curl, debe salir `cURL support  enabled `. No te olvides de remover dicho fichero una vez que hayas visto la configuración de tu servidor.

Comment: ok , disculpa que sea muy noob , la carpeta publica eso es desde godaddy o en mi proyecto lo cree en la raiz de mi proyecto pero como lo ejecuto

Comment: si tienes acceso al servidor de godaddy, en el servidor de godaddy, porque en tu local no valdria mucho la pena revisar si lo activas, creas el archivo, le añades esa linea simplemente y lo revisas como una página, `http://miservidor.net/info.php` y te mostrara una serie de cosas, debes buscar curl, y obtendras algo así `cURL support enabled`

Comment: si de hecho si me aparece en anabled , entonces ahi ya no deberia agregar el dll o deberia importar algo aun?

Comment: no, con eso ya funcionaria el llamado curl que necesitas sobre tu servidor, alguna otra duda?

Comment: pues ya se que si esta activado el curl , el problema pues sigue siendo por que no me funciona el curl por que como te digo hice el try catch pero me sigue marcando el error del unexpected token en esa parte pero si esta bien

Comment: agregare mi codigo abajo en otra respuesta

Comment: agregalo sobre la misma pregunta

Comment: ya me retorno correctamente el webservice , creo que tenia un error al agregar la primer linea del xml , en el .= estaba solo como igual entonces se perdia la primer linea , tambien la peticion curl ya me dio respuesta pero no modifique nada al parecer era error del servicio